# Skipping an Element when serializing a "MessageBodyMember" property

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, xml-serialization

Whenever object of a class marked with **MessageContract** attribute is serialized, I see that it looks for **[MessageBodyMember]** members and serializes them under seperate XML elements in the message. Is there anyway to directly serialize them, skipping the wrapper node ?

Eg.

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
Class A
{
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string MyMessage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

When this gets serialized it becomes

```
<Body>
<MyMessage>....</MyMessage>
</Body>
```

but i want it to become

```
<Body>
....
</Body>
```

I know this might be illogical. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want (i.e., replace the ... with the some example)? For example, do you want a message to look like this <s:Envelope><s:Body>Some string</s:Body></s:Envelope>?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:-

```
[MessageBodyMember(Name="Body")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to remove the `<MyMessage>` element and have the string itself on the message body. Well, the message contract won't work for you. You can remove the outer wrapper for the message contract, but not the wrappers for individual members.

What you can do, is to create a `Message` object based on a `BodyWriter` instance you create, and this body writer can write the output XML in whatever form it wants to. See the code below for an example.

```
public class StackOverflow_7010654
{
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class MyMC
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string MyMessage { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        TypedMessageConverter tmc = TypedMessageConverter.Create(typeof(MyMC), "Action");
        Message msg = tmc.ToMessage(new MyMC { MyMessage = "some string" }, MessageVersion.Soap11);
        Console.WriteLine(msg); // message with the <MyMessage> element

        Console.WriteLine();

        msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "Action", new MyBodyWriter());
        Console.WriteLine(msg); // message without the <MyMessage> element
    }
    public class MyBodyWriter : BodyWriter
    {
        public MyBodyWriter() : base(true) { }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteString("some string");
        }
    }
}
```